# Schengen visa extension due to flight cancellation

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, overstaying, delays

I have a Schengen visa valid for 30 days with 14 days stay. This was as per itinerary planned by me. In my return trip I will be traveling from Frankfurt to Bangalore via Paris.

Suddenly my connecting flight from Paris to Bangalore has been cancelled and I have been accommodated by airline in next day's flight. But my visa is not valid for that additional day and it will be 15th day in Schengen area.

Please advise.

Comment: You need to contact the airline to get your flight changed to a date within your visa validity or apply for a new visa. It’s unlikely that the visa-issuing authority would view the flight cancellation as sufficient reason to extend your visa since flight schedule changes by airlines occur frequently and can be planned for by the traveller eg by not booking their exit flight for the last day.

Comment: I had informed about my itinerary while applying for visa. Visa issuing authority has issued visa for exact number of days of my stay planned in Shenzhen area.

Comment: Make sure to collect as much evidence from airline, e.g. cancellation letter, etc. This situation never happened to me but I imagine it may come in handy.

Comment: Thanks rvs for your help however, is there any rule which helps in such situations.

Comment: Definitely **talk to the airline first**, to hear if they are willing to rebook you a day earlier rather than a day later. Just because their initial suggestion was to move you a day later doesn't mean it's the only thing they will accept. (And you'd need to present some kind of evidence that you have _tried_ to move your travel earlier, if you want to get a force-majeure visa extension).

Answer (score 3):

A Schengen visa **can** be extended if departure is prevented by "force majeure" such as unexpectedly closed airports (see the link in the question that was tagged as duplicate). The reason why I write this answer is one important addition: The application for an extension should be done *before* the visa expires. If you are already at Frankfurt airport, you might ask the Bundespolizei if there is a visa office open on a Saturday evening.