# Extending a short-term visa issued from Germany in Hungary?

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-extensions

I know that short term visas are subject to strict rules when it comes to extensions. Is it possible to extend a short-term visa issued from Germany in Hungary?

The purpose or the reason for the question is:
1- I live in Budapest as a student and my fiancee has a Schengen visa C from Germany. 
2- We're gonna be married in a european country next month.
3- Then she'll apply for a normal spouse visa to join me in Hungary.

However, A lawyer told me that it's possible to request an extension for her C visa until the spouse visa get issued for her. So my question is will she extend it from Hungary or Germany. "I know the whole extension may get denied I'm just asking about the possibility for extending from a different country than Germany"

Comment: Your question isn’t very clear, however this answer seems related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135199/schengen-visa-extension-due-to-flight-cancellation

Comment: The answer depends on (1) whether your extension would take you over the limit of 90 days in any 180-day period, and (2) the reason for the extension.  Under the Schengen rules, any Schengen country can temporarily permit someone to remain in its territory by issuing a residence permit, but most countries do not allow in-country applications unless the applicant already has a national (type D) visa specifically for that purpose. Without more information about the circumstances, this question does not lend itself to a satisfying answer. Voting to close as unclear; if you edit I will retract.

Comment: I did Edit it I hope I made things a little bit clear. She will not exceed the 90 days in any 180 days I'm sure.